# How to find the predicted input from new output after I trained my neural network?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, training-data

I have a large data set, which I used to train a neural network. Now I want to use it on new output, is it possible to get the input prediction for this output ?

The model script as follows:

```matlab
    % Solve an Input-Output Fitting problem with a Neural Network

    % This script assumes these variables are defined:
% '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    data - input data.
    data_1 - target data.

    x = data';
    t = data_1';


    trainFcn = 'trainlm';  % Levenberg-Marquardt backpropagation.
% ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
    % Create a Fitting Network
    hiddenLayerSize = 10;
    net = fitnet(hiddenLayerSize,trainFcn);

    % Setup Division of Data for Training, Validation, Testing
    net.divideParam.trainRatio = 70/100;
    net.divideParam.valRatio = 15/100;
    net.divideParam.testRatio = 15/100;

    % Train the Network
    [net,tr] = train(net,x,t);
% ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
    % Test the Network`  data - input data.
    data_1 - target data.

    x = data';
    t = data_1';


    trainFcn = 'trainlm';  % Levenberg-Marquardt backpropagation.

    % Create a Fitting Network
    hiddenLayerSize = 10;
    net = fitnet(hiddenLayerSize,trainFcn);

    % Setup Division of Data for Training, Validation, Testing
    net.divideParam.trainRatio = 70/100;
    net.divideParam.valRatio = 15/100;
    net.divideParam.testRatio = 15/100;

    % Train the Network
    [net,tr] = train(net,x,t);

    % Test the Network
    y = net(x);
    e = gsubtract(t,y);
    performance = perform(net,t,y)

    view(net)`
    y = net(x);
    e = gsubtract(t,y);
    performance = perform(net,t,y)
    view(net)
```

I would like to insert new output and predict what input could have been. How can I do that?

Comment: Just to be clear, you have your terms confused right? You want to use new **input** to predict **output**, not the other way around

Comment: @adriaan no i am not confused, i want to know what is the optimal input conditions for my output.

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate your network with

```
output = sim(net,input)
```

Comment: thank you, but my purpose is finding the best combination of my input ( optimum input values for my desired output)

Comment: @SaedRawash that is quite confusing actually. Care to explain? I mean, the entire purpose of making neural networks is to have the opposite of what you are saying. You give the input, thus it makes no sense to "find" inputs, as well, by the definition of the word, its what you give to the algorithm, not what the algorithm searches. Care to explain further what are you doing?